# Getting only the title of a youtube video for my Android app

Tags: android, youtube

I wish to show the list of videos for a particular youtube channel in my android app. 
I am getting the thumbnail images for the videos using urls similar to:

http://img.youtube.com/vi/GDFUdMvacI0/1.jpg

Is there any url or any other way to get the title for these videos?

Comment: Maybe this can help: [Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/code#client_libraries)

Answer (score 0):

Extract the title FROM atom feed sent by youtube. A sample feed is [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_understanding_video_feeds#Understanding_Feeds_and_Entries).

Parse it and you can get the title.
The title is present inside the entry tag.